# OO pattern for dividing a collection into groups

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a list of MyObjects which I need to divide into three groups:

1. Known good (keep)
2. Known bad (reject)
3. Unrecognized (raise alert)

MyObject contains various properties which must be examined to determine which of the 3 groups to put the object in.

My initial implementation (Java) just takes a List in its constructor and does the triage there. Pseudocode:

```
class MyObjectFilterer {
  public MyObjectFilterer(List<MyObject> list) {
    // triage items here
  }
  public List<MyObject> getGood() {
    // return sub-list of good items
  }
  public List<MyObject> getBad() {
    // return sub-list of bad items
  }
  public List<MyObject> getUnrecognized() {
    // return sub-list of unrecognized items
  }
}
```

Any issues with this implementation? Is there a better OO choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably prefer a static factory method to do the filtering, that then calls a private constructor that takes the three filtered lists, following the good code practice of never doing any serious work in a constructor.  Other than that, this looks fine.

Comment: I know you are a bit down on the overuse or wrong use of Guava functional paradigms, but as part of the Guava team, you're not going to suggest the use of `Predicate`s and `Iterables.filter()`?

Comment: Absolutely not.  For starters, the OP wants to split the list into three different categories.  Even using `Iterables.filter` -- the OP would be using `Predicate`s, not `Function`s, and remember that there isn't a `Lists.filter` method -- that would require three traversals of the target list, rather than a single one.  Not only would functional idioms make this less readable, it'd make it strictly less efficient.

Comment: I was busy editing my post to use Predicates before I saw your reply.  I see your point, as it applies to the question as directly asked.  I guess I was thinking what was _possibly_ behind the question.  Is the goal actually to have three physical collections, or was the goal to have a means for classifying each element of a single collection as needed?  If the latter, then would it still be inappropriate to suggest the use of Predicates as distributed classifiers, if you don't want to add the logic to the objects being classified?

Comment: I specifically don't think `Predicate`s are appropriate to divide the input into _three_ categories, although if there were only two categories it might be a bit more reasonable.  As it stands, the OP's approach is straightforward, readable, and even if the true problem is somewhat different, this is a perfectly good solution, and I'm inclined to stick with it by and large.

Comment: Thanks for the comments... I was particularly interested if Iterables.filter would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple approachs. If the problem is generic / repetitive enough, you could define an interface with a method to classify the objects.

```
interface Selector {
  public boolean isGood(MyObject myObject);
  public boolean isBad(MyObject myObject);
  public boolean isUnknown(MyObject myObject);
```

}

That way you could change the logic implementation easily.

Answer (score 0):

An other idea would be using the Chain of responsibility.

Your **MyObjectFilterer** contains a reference to three Objects **GoodFilterer**, **BadFilterer** and **UnrecognizedFilterer**. Each of them contains the following methods: **addMethod(MyObject object)**, **getObjects()** and **addFilter()**. Of course they have to implement an interface **Filterer**.

With the **addFilter** method you can build the chain. so that the **GoodFilterer** contains a reference to the **BadFilterer** and this one contains a reference to the **UnrecognizedFilterer**

Now you go through your list of **MyObjects** and call the add method on the **GoodFilterer** (first one in this chain). Inside the add method you decide if this is good, than you keep it and finish the work, if not pass it on to the **BadFilterer**.

You keep your three methods for getting the good/bad and unrecognized, but you will pass this to the **getObjects()** method of the corresponding **Filterer**

The Benefit is that the logic if this is a good/bad or Unrecognized one is now seperated.

The Downside you would need 3 new classes and 1 Interface.

But like i said, this is just an other idea what you could do.

Comment: It appears that the categories in this case are mutually exclusive, and therefore possibly interdependent (i.e., can only be Bad or Unrecognized if it is first known to NOT be Good).  So I'm not sure you want to separate the logic for computing good/bad/unrecognized

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify as it's possible. Just make static method in MyObjectFilter with following signature:

public static List filterMyObjects(List data, Group group).

Group is enumeration with three values and it can be used as attribute of MyObject class

Comment: probably not good to make the enumeration a property of the objects, because if the objects have other mutable fields used in the categorization, their classification could change and you would have to keep the categorization property in synch with any changes to the object.  Better to keep categorization logic/properties external to the class.

Comment: Sorry, I did't understand everything correctly from your question. I thought Group is actually belongs in your class as field. I would still prefer to have one static method and to use group enum (renamed in FilterOption) as argument of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I might try something like:

```
enum MyObjectStatus {
   GOOD, BAD, UNRECOGNIZED;
}

class MyObjectFilterer {
  private MyObjectStatus getStatus(MyObject obj) {
    // classify logic here, returns appropriate enum value
  }

  // ListMultimap return type below is from Google Guava
  public ListMultimap<MyObjectStatus, MyObject> classify(List<MyObject> objects) {
     ListMultimap<MyObjectStatus, MyObject> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();
     for(MyObject obj: objects) {
        map.put(getStatus(obj), obj);
     }
  }
}
```

Call classify() to get a Multimap, and extract each category as needed with something like:

```
List<MyObject> good = map.get(GOOD);
List<MyObject> bad = map.get(BAD);
List<MyObject> unknown = map.get(UNRECOGNIZED);
```

A nice thing about this solution is you don't have to create/publish accessor methods for each category (unless you want to), and if new categories are created, you also don't add new accessors -- just the new enum and the additional classifier logic.